# Search path for pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm creating some tables reading values from `.dat` files. All these files are placed in a subfolder. Is there a way to tell `\pgfplotstabletypeset` the search path to that subfolder? Something similar to `\graphicspath`?

Extra info: I have my files organized in subfolders but I'm trying to submit a paper to a journal and I cannot create subfolders on their build servers (I have to upload the files one by one and they end up in a single folder). I also cannot set `TEXINPUTS` (unless there's a way to do it from the main `.tex` file).

PS: I find it frustrating that scientific journals have retarded `tex` build servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such builtin feature in `pgfplotstable`. In fact, this question resembles an old feature request.

While thinking about alternatives, I got the following idea:

You could place some dummy text file like `thisisremuspc.file` in your aside of your local directory structure and add something like

```
\IfFileExists{thisisremuspc.file}{\def\todirectory##1{##1}}{\def\todirectory##1{}}
```

to your preamble. Whenever you load a data file, you could write

```
\addplot table {\todirectory{my/local/sub/dir/}file.dat};
```

I have had no time to test this approach, but it should work (up to, maybe, magic due to the `#` characters). The idea is that `todirectory` would expand to an empty string if you magic file is missing. Would that do the job (assuming it works)?

Answer (score 6):

`pgfplotstable` v 1.13 comes with a builtin solution: the key `search path`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{dir/data.dat}
x y
1 2
3 4
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[search path={dir}]{data.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The argument is a comma-separated list of directory names (including `.` or `..`). Note that `.` is actually TEXINPUTS, i.e. the normal TeX search path.